# Is there any command line client to do data entry in DHIS2?

Tags: dhis-2

I want to know is there any command line client to do data entry in DHIS2?

I found one, named as dish (https://github.com/baosystems/dish2/), but it is only used for simplifying common tasks and is suitable for handling batch metadata operations, system maintenance operations.

I want to enter data into data elements directly, is it possible? If not there is any alternative method to it?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, there are no command line clients to do data entry for DHIS2. There are however options to import data into DHIS2 using xml, json or csv formats. So one option is to create the data in one of these formats first, then use the API to import it.

When you say you want to enter data into data elements directly, I assume you are referring to actual data and not metadata.

There is no way to interact with the DHIS2 api to add data directly to a data element. The reason for this is that data elements are either connected to a data set or, if you are using the tracker models, a program stage. A single data element can be connected to multiple data sets or program stages, so adding data directly to a data element wouldn't make sense.

You can however do data entry for a data element, but you need to go through either a data set or program stage that uses the data element.

What is your use-case for needing a command line client for this? Maybe I know of another solution that would help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. :)
I want to do data entry from the backend. Is there any another option?

Comment: @Sachinchougule, in that case you either have to go trough the REST api, or do the data entry directly to the database. I would suggest using the REST api in that case:) For example by creating your payload as a file and using the REST api for importing data

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the suggestions :). 
I will do it by using the import option in DHIS.